# How to solve Datafusion upload custom plugin 502 bad gateway error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am getting 502 bad gateway error when I tried uploading a custom plugin using datafusion (Enterprise edition) UI. I tried multiple times and still having the same issue. How to resolve this issue.
Below screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: first thing I would like you to try is to set up a new Data Fusion instance and install the plugin. Can you try that and tell me if it worked?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, i even tried this way also. Still this error appears.

Comment: did you apply some customization to your code? Also,  have you check any compatibility issues with your plugin and CDF environment?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, I cloned existing plugin from github and try to upload the same.

Comment: Can you try to upload the plugin in a different browser ? Also, [Data Fusion](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/) is built on the open source project CDAP. For this reason, can you also try to run your job using [CDAP](https://cdap.io/get-started/)?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, I tried uploading plugin in chrome and also from firefox and faced the same error in both. I would like to use datafusion only. I tried in CDAP and it is fast over there.

Comment: so did it work using CDAP?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, It worked using CDAP. Only problem with datafusion when accessing from chrome or firefox. BTW were you able to replicate the issue from your end?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes, were you able to replicate this issue?